# How to fix Asp.net Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Asp.net Solution that has three Projects, this solution deleted when i pressed delete key 'By wrong' and i recovered the solution using a software recovering files but the solution recovered but it is corrupted 
Is there any way to Fix this Corruption? 
Help Please.

Comment: How it's corcupted ? Did you get some error messages ? 
Maybe two other project have references to this one that you deleted and vice versa.

Comment: this is the message when trying to open the solution 'the selected file is not a valid solution file'

Comment: this is the message when trying to open the solution 'the selected file is not a valid solution file'
and all classes opened as notepad with strange symbols

Comment: Your data recovery probably didnt work correctly. Should be fine to open sln files in notepad. If you are only missing your sln file you could always just create a new one and add your existing csproj to the new sln.

Comment: And this is why you should use Source Control - there are various free options (not that this will help you now, unfortunately)